# WPF Bitmap transparent background turns black

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I have a listbox with Items that all have a random background color.
In each Item of the listbox i want to display a Bitmap picture.
Now for some reason the background of each bitmap (which I've set to Color.Transparent) Shows up black.

Here a picture of how it looks

[image: Background not transparent]

My code for the listbox:

```
 <WrapPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6" >
        <ListBox x:Name="CharListBox" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListToDisplay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate1}"
             SelectionChanged="SelectionChangedNewCharSelected">

        </ListBox>
    </WrapPanel>
```

The item template (I removed everything beside the image part for bettter overview):

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate1" >
        <Image Source="{Binding OutfitImageSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="40" Width="40" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Binding binds to a BitmapSource.

Is it possible that bitmaps dont have actual transparency, its just shown as black?
I also tried to add `AllowsTransparency="True"` to the window properties, this just lead to the window crashing instantly..

Thank you for helping in advance!

**update:** AllowsTransparency works if i set `WindowStyle="None"` but it still does not fix the problem with the untransparent bitmaps.

Comment: do not use bitmaps in the first place. use photoshop or Paint.NET to modify these images **by hand** and then use them in your project. you may need to do more than saving them as PNG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reported in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/180960)

> Bitmaps (i.e. files with .BMP extension) do not natively support transparency: you need to save as a different format like PNG.

You can find the same info also [here](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1290#p14668).

So it does not depend on your XAML or your code. Just save your bitmaps as PNG files and then use those files for your application.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
Is there a way to Convert my Bitmaps into .png and save them as Bitmapsources?
Or will do i have to change everything from the bottom to get the transparency?

Comment: You are welcome @YoungMister. You can use the [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) class for opening your BMP file and then save it as a PNG (just call `bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);`).

Comment: Thank you @ll Vic. I played arround with it for a while.